# multiple table LINQ-SQL query using anonymous types

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm running ASP.NET MVC + LINQ-to-SQL using .NET 4.0.

I have query similar to this:

```
var labels = (from c in db.Customers
join o in db.Orders
on c.CustID equals o.CustID
select o).Distinct();
```

Can I do the same with an anonymous query, something like this

`Customers.Select(x => x.Orders)` ??

How would I do this if my query depth is 3 or 4 tables deep?

Comment: That syntax is called "Lambda". Anyonymous types are an entirely different concept. It means that you return (from whatever linq, or lambda, or anything else) an anonymous type. You should check online for definitions about linq query, lambda expression and anonymous type to clear your mind.

Comment: @Matteo: Ah ok now _that_ makes sense.

Comment: Yeah I know I could give a complete explanation like yours. Excellent explanation btw.

Answer (score 0):

The query you have there is more or less equivalent to this:

```
var labels = db.Customers
    .Join(db.Orders, c => c.CustID, o => o.CustId, (c, o) => o)
    .Distinct();
```

FYI, it can go by different names.  "Lambda" syntax is a common one.  "Fluent" syntax is another.  There's nothing anonymous about it.  Anonymous types on the other hand is an unnamed type defined like so:

```
var anonymousObject = new { SomeField = 2, SomeOtherField = "Foo" };
```